# Multiple services type in Android targetSdkVersion 34

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-manifest, targetsdkversion

I have a service using 2 types `mediaPlayback` and `microphone` and declared like this in AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE" />

 <service
            android:name=".player.SomeService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="MusicAndMicroService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback|microphone">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

On **When targetSdkVerion 34 and on Android 14**, we also need pass service type constant when calling `startForeground()`.

Currently I call like this:

```
ServiceCompat.startForeground(service, R.id.exampleNotiId, notificationBuilder.build(),
                            ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK or ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE)
```

As a result it will do a bitwise and my value pass to `startForeground` will be wrong.
Anyone have solution for this when update targetsdkversion to 34?
Thank you for your help